# Symfony2: How to manage lists of things to show in form and use in PHP classes

Tags: php, forms, symfony, select, doctrine-orm

Having a list of "things" (for example, a list of cities) to display in a select option form field type, how should I manage it?

For example, take the following very short list of cities:

- [0] Salerno;
- [1] New York;
- [2] Paris;
- [3] Chicago;
- [4] New Delhi;

I would like to do the following things:

1. Show them in the form select field type;
2. Store them in the database using their index (0 for Salerno, 1 for New York and so on);
3. Transform them into strings from the index when I retrieve the information from the database through Doctrine.

One alternative could be the use of a class full of constants, but maybe there is a better solution, so I'm asking here for it! :)

Thank you!

Comment: 3 very simple questions that already have an answer in the symfony2 documentation, just read it. 1 question: [Form Types](http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/types.html), 2 question: [Databases and Doctrine](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/doctrine.html), 3 question: [How to Use Data Transformers](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/form/data_transformers.html)

Answer (score 0):

Super easy, use the entity field type. This allows you to use an entity to list the Choices, it even handles mapping the indexes for you.

http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/types/entity.html

```
$builder->add('users', 'entity', array(
    'class' => 'AcmeHelloBundle:User',
    'property' => 'username',
));
```

The class maps to your entity class. the property tells it which property on the class to show to the user in the select.

Answer (score 0):

A hopefully more direct answer: the most straightforward technique would be to create a City entity. It would look like this:

```
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * City
 *
 * @ORM\Table(name="city")
 * @ORM\Entity
 */
class City
{
    /**
     * @var integer
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="IDENTITY")
     */
    protected $id;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="city", type="string", length=15, nullable=false)
     */
    protected $city;

    /**
     * Set city
     *
     * @param string $city
     * @return City
     */
    public function setCity($city)
    {
        $this->city = $city;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get city
     *
     * @return string 
     */
    public function getCity()
    {
        return $this->city;
    }

}
```

In a form class you could add City as an entity type (see Chausser's answer for documentation reference).

The city's name could be returned in a controller with something like

```
$em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
$city = $em->getRepository("YourBundle:City")->find($id);
$cityName = $city->getCity();
```